# Brute Force Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, cryptography, brute-force

For no particular reason, other than I am interesting in cryptography and computing, I would like to make my own brute force program in Java or Visual Basic or C# to see if it can crack a password. I am not interested in performance and I am aware that it is a totally impractical method - it's just a bit of a fun project to be honest. However, I've only got a rough idea in my head and I can't even put it into psuedocode. I'm most proficient in Java but even if somebody could provide me with the psuedocode that'd be great!

I don't want to provide the program with a length, but I'll provide a maximum length. I know that the program will have to do a lot of work, but I do also think I am overthinking it a little.

Comment: Hmm...generate a password. Test it. Generate another. Test it. Continue 'til found. Without details of the system, saying much more is difficult.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any research into this? We aren't going to just provide you with psuedocode. And by brute force, are you planning to just have a program try to log into a system repeatedly or are you going to be determine password in a stolen password file. For most system with good security, the first method shouldn't work because they would eventually block you.

Comment: As I said, I am not creating this program for any other reason than personal satisfaction! I'm not planning to hack because I know it is a somewhat ridiculous method. I've done all of the research, I just can't find an algorithm in a programming language I can understand! I'll be honest, the only thing I've attempted is the psuedocode but I just can't get my head around the logic.

Comment: @Downvoters please could you explain why you downvoted my question because I think it is perfectly reasonable. It may seem a bit pointless but it is something I would like to do and I do think it would be slightly beneficial too

Comment: @Andy I didn't downvote, but for starters - I don't see a question in your question.  Not a single question mark....anywhere.  What IS your question?

Comment: @Luke Ok, so maybe there isn't a question mark but I did think I was asking for help by putting " I'm most proficient in Java but even if somebody could provide me with the psuedocode that'd be great!". Maybe I should have made it a bit more clear that I just wanted the algorithm for a brute force password cracker type program - like the function in the code I have now posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I just found an example what I wanted to do in C++ and I've managed to convert it to the following Visual Basic .NET code, which works perfectly. However the output seems a bit slow and I'd have thought the program would have used near 100% processing power, but it isn't. Could somebody tell me why this is and how I could change it please?

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim chars() As Char = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYX".ToCharArray
    Dim csize As Integer = chars.Length - 1
    Dim upto As String
    Private Sub btnGo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
        upto = "                                                  "

        Dim max_length As Integer = 50

        For i = 1 To max_length
            bf_recursion(0, i)
            Update()
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub bf_recursion(ByVal index As Integer, ByVal depth As Integer)
        Dim current() As Char = upto.ToCharArray()

        For i = 0 To csize
            current(index) = chars(i)
            upto = CStr(current)

            Console.WriteLine(CStr(current))
            '\\lblOutput.Text = CStr(current)

            If index <> (depth - 1) Then
                bf_recursion(index + 1, depth)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The code is likely maxing out 1 core of the CPU, thus Task Manager will report that the overall CPU Utilization is not 100%.  To fully utilize all cores, you would have to make it multi-threaded.  And you would have to deal with the synchronization issues that arise from that approach.  This is completely possible, but not trivial.

Comment: @Luke I have a Intel Core i7 2620M processor which has two physical cores / four logical cores and Task Manager is showing a maximum of 10% CPU usage. What you said makes sense and I'm not going to go to the hassle of making the application multi-threaded, but theoretically shouldn't it use at least 25%?

Comment: That seems logical.  Without running and testing the code myself, the only other thought is that the algorithm is bound by something other than CPU.  I'm no wiz with VB, but it looks like the application is printing out every guess to the console, right?  That might be slowing it down.  If that's not it, then I'd say the application is memory bound.  That is, reading from and writing to memory is taking longer than the actual calculations.  Therefore the application uses less than 100% of the available CPU core.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you will want to do is figure out what you want to brute force. I would pick a one way hashing scheme, such as MD5 or SHA-1, that can be brute forced at high rates. After choosing which one way hashing scheme you want to "break", you will have to find some sort of password list, like http://www.whatsmypass.com/the-top-500-worst-passwords-of-all-time. After you have the list you need to hash the values and store them somewhere. After you have this stored "real" data set, you create your brute force loop and compare. When you find a match, output that match. You have now "cracked" a fake person password via brute force. Good luck!

Comment: This is actually more a dictionary attack, than a true brute-force one.

Comment: Thank you but I was under the impression that this is more like a dictionary attack, and really all I want to do is go through all the permutations of a password with a maximum length if that makes more sense. I'm not going to necessarily even hash the password, I just want to create a program that generates a string via a brute force method to be honest.

Comment: No, the dictionary provided is a set of things to be cracked. A dictionary attack would be using that list to attack another data set. The point of getting the data set in this example to so you don't have to brute force an actual live site. You would just be cracking a set. Equivalent to a data leak that releases the password hashes of a large company, like LinkdIn.http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/06/06/linkedin-passwords-stolen_n_1574075.html?ref=technology

Comment: @Scott Ok, thank you for that clarification but your answer is still not really what I wanted to achieve. I just want to run through all the permutations of a string with a certain length and character set. Can you help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

Hasan-G: yes i can

```
Dim chars() As Char = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray
    Dim csize As Integer = chars.Length - 1
    Dim upto As String
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        upto = "                                                  "

        Dim max_length As Integer = 25

        For i = 1 To max_length
            bf_recursion(0, i)
            Update()
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub bf_recursion(ByVal index As Integer, ByVal depth As Integer)
        Dim current() As Char = upto.ToCharArray()

        For i = 0 To csize
            current(index) = chars(i)
            upto = CStr(current)

            TextBox1.Text = (CStr(current))
            TextBox1.Refresh()
            Me.Refresh()
            '\\lblOutput.Text = CStr(current)

            If index <> (depth - 1) Then
                bf_recursion(index + 1, depth)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
while (true) 
{

 string[] mystring = new string[27];
                    mystring[0] = "";
                    mystring[1] = "a";
                    mystring[2] = "b";
                    mystring[3] = "c";
                    mystring[4] = "d";
                    mystring[5] = "e";
                    mystring[6] = "f";
                    mystring[7] = "g";
                    mystring[8] = "h";
                    mystring[9] = "i";
                    mystring[10] = "j";
                    mystring[11] = "k";
                    mystring[12] = "l";
                    mystring[13] = "m";
                    mystring[14] = "n";
                    mystring[15] = "o";
                    mystring[16] = "p";
                    mystring[17] = "q";
                    mystring[18] = "r";
                    mystring[19] = "s";
                    mystring[20] = "t";
                    mystring[21] = "u";
                    mystring[22] = "v";
                    mystring[23] = "w";
                    mystring[24] = "x";
                    mystring[25] = "y";
                    mystring[26] = "z";



                    if (counter == 27)
                    {
                        counter = 0;
                        counter2++;
                    }

                    if (counter2 == 27)
                    {
                        counter2 = 0;
                        counter3++;
                    }

                    if (counter3 == 27)
                    {
                        counter3 = 0;
                        counter4++;
                    }

                    if (counter4 == 27)
                    {
                        counter4 = 0;
                        counter5++;
                    }

                    if (counter5 == 27)
                    {
                        counter5 = 0;
                        counter6++;
                    }

                    if (counter6 == 27)
                    {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }



                    guessedpassword =  mystring[counter6] + mystring[counter5] + mystring[counter4] + mystring[counter3] + mystring[counter2] + mystring[counter];


                    counter++;
    }
```

Here is some code i have written. It is very inefficient at cracking, but is simple.